# how to add additional hard (second) hard drive to Hyper-V Server 2008 R2

Tags: hard-drive, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We currently have a Dell PowerEdge T110 server with a 250GB SATA HDD.

[image: Spec of machine]

It is running Hyper-V server 2008 R2 (the bare metal hyper visor thing that doesn't have the full GUI).  We are running out of space and want to add a second 1TB drive to the machine.  If I buy a 1TB SATA HDD and add it into the machine, when I reboot will it pick it up?  Can I use it?

This is our first time using Hyper-V Server and I am not 100% sure if this will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll just need to initialize and partition the disk using DISKPART from the command line.